# Keep HDMI connection alive after the display has switched off

Tags: ubuntu, display, hdmi

I have my machine set up to switch off the display after 5 minutes of inactivity, however it switches it off, then the monitor shows "No signal" and turns off, then it goes back on (without me moving the mouse or pressing a key) and I'm left with ruined environment (I use XMonad and stuff).

Is it possible to keep HDMI connection alive after the display has switched off?

I'm on XUbuntu 20.04.